# Generating .ovpn Config for android phone

Tags: networking, server, android, openvpn

I'm using an Ubuntu Server and I wanted to use `OpenVpn`  for my server and my android phone. I installed OpenVpn connect for my phone and the software needs `*.ovpn` file from my server. How can I generate this file? And how can I enable authentication? I've use `OpenVpn Access Server` but it gives only two users licensee to authenticate but I need more. I've searched through internet but all training I've found was how to generate `client.key` , `client.crt` and `ca.crt` but I can't use them for my android phone.

Comment: what about generating one in ubuntu. I tried your example but it asks me for password. I didnt setup any password.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you create a `.ovpn` file:

Create a new txt file and rename as `yourname.ovpn`. Paste the following in into the txt file and replace with your domain name:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote YOUR.DOMAIN 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
```

a reference is here: http://lukasz.cepowski.com/devlog/32,sample-openvpn-client-config-ovpn

Otherwise if you are using OpenVPN Access Server (which I would recommend), once you've set up your profile, you can get the .ovpn file in your similar directory of: `C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN Technologies\OpenVPN Client\etc\profile`